# Nested loop results in table, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to loop a computation over two lists of elements and save the results in a table. So, say that

```py
months = [1,2,3,4,5]
Region = ['Region1', 'Region2']
```

and that my code is of the type

```py
df=[]
for month in month:
    for region in Region:
        code 
        x = result
        df.append(x)
```

What I cannot achieve is rendering the final result in a table in which the rows are regions and coumns are months

```
                 1            2          3          4          5

    Region1      a            b          c          d          e
    
    Region2      f            g          h          i          j
```

Comment: What are the variables `code` and `result` in your code ? In `for month in month:` the second month should have an `s` at the end.

Comment: Sorry for missing the s. As for code, it is not a variable (I didn't want to write all the steps of my computation. So code is the what happens within the loop. result is the value obtained at the end of each loop.

Comment: And the `a`-`j` are the results of each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution - more lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
months = [1,2,3,4,5]
Regions = ['Region1', 'Region2']
       
df = pd.DataFrame()
for region in Regions:
    row = '{\'Region\': \'' +  region +'\', '
    for month in months:
        # put your calculation code
        x = month + 1
        row = row + '\'' + str(month) + '\':[' + str(x) + '],'
    row = row[:len(row)-1] + '}'
    row = ast.literal_eval(row)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(row))
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is the right numbers of items in `result`

```
result = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Region = ['Region1', 'Region2']
df = pd.DataFrame([[Region[i]] + result[i*len(months): ((i+1)*len(months))] for i in range(len(Region))], columns=["Region"] + months).set_index("Region")
```

Output

```
         1  2  3  4  5
Region                
Region1  a  b  c  d  e
Region2  f  g  h  i  j
```

---

This part

```
[[Region[i]] + result[i*len(months): ((i+1)*len(months))] for i in range(len(Region))]
```

is equivalent to something like this

```
res = []
for i in range(len(Region)):
    row = [Region[i]] + result[i*len(months): ((i+1)*len(months))]
    res.append(row)
```

where I use the length of `Region` to slice `result` in equals part for each row. And I add the name of the region at the begging of the row.

Comment: This is great, but I still can't make it populate the dataframe with the results `result = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`

Comment: This is brilliant!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This might work, depending on what and how y want the results.

```
import pandas as pd
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Region = ['Region1', 'Region2']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 2, 3])  # just to put in something
value = 59
for r in Region:
    value += 5
    for m in months:
        df.loc[r, m] = chr(m+value)
```